# Error checking with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm having trouble finding any information on how to do error checking on MySQLdb. I have been trying to do a simple update command for a MySQL database and it simply is not working. No matter how I change the terms, or the type of variables I submit to it.

Here are some of my (commented out) attempts:

```
timeid = twitseek['max_id']
            #timeup = "UPDATE `timeid` set `timestamp`='" + str(timeid) + "';"
            #print timeup
            #c.execute(timeup)

            #timeup = "UPDATE timeid SET timestamp=\"" + str(timeid) + "\"";
            #timeup = "UPDATE timeid set timestamp = '500';"
            timeup = 500
            c.execute("""UPDATE timeid SET timestamp = %d;""", timeup)
            #c.execute(timeup)
```

All I want to do is upload the value of `timeid` to the `timestamp` column's first value (or any value) in the table `timeid`.

Nothing I do seems to work and I've been sitting here for literally hours trying countless iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing an obligatory call to `.commit()` on your connection object to commit your change.

```
# Your cursor is c
# We don't see your connection object, but assuming it is conn...
c.execute("""UPDATE timeid SET timestamp = %d;""", timeup)
conn.commit()
```

The above method will produce valid SQL, but you don't get the security benefit of prepared statements this way. The proper method to pass in parameters is to use `%s`, and pass in a tuple of parameters:

```
c.execute("UPDATE timeid SET timestamp = %s;", (timeup,))
conn.commit()
```

#### From [the MySQLdb FAQ:](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html)

> Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default, as
>   required by the DB-API standard (PEP-249). If you are using InnoDB
>   tables or some other type of transactional table type, you'll need to
>   do connection.commit() before closing the connection, or else none of
>   your changes will be written to the database.
>
> Conversely, you can also use connection.rollback() to throw away any
>   changes you've made since the last commit.

As far as error checking goes, a failed connection or a syntactically invalid query will throw an exception. So you would want to wrap it in a `try/except` as is common in Python.

Comment: Yea, I tried passing a tuple first, but that didn't work either. I also tried just concatenating the variables into the string too, haha!

Comment: Yes, I am trying it with a .commit() currently.

Comment: It worked. So any time I want to make a change to a database (i.e. insert, update or delete), I should be using the .commit() method?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Yep, any modification requires .commit() since auto-commit is disabled by default. This is [in the MySQLdb FAQ](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html), but it's too bad the documentation isn't a little more thorough for MySQLdb.  This comes up often.